# Read the values of form in controller

Tags: php, symfony, web, doctrine-orm

How I can retrieve the values of a form that was just validated? but I want to manipulate the values in the controller. I have this code to retrieve the information, but was not handled in the controller php.

```
        if ($form->isValid ()) {

        $recuperacion = $form->getData (); 
        $em = $this->getDoctrine ()->getManager ();
        $em->persist ( $recuperacion ); // Inserta la información en la base de datos
        $em->flush ();

       /* I want get the values here... */
       /* _____________________________ */

        $this->InsertarAdminPV ( $user );

        return $this->redirect ( $this->generateUrl ( 'md_listapv' ) );
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does "but was not handled in the controller php" mean? Could you show us how you create the form and handle the request?

Comment: 1. You're already getting them with `$recuperacion = $form->getData (); `, what is the problem then? 2. `$request->request->get($form->getName())` didn't help?

Comment: Could you post the code for getData(); ?

Comment: You don't even need the `$form->getData()` function if you've performed `$form->handleRequest($request)` before calling `$form->isValid()` since the Form Handler will persist the form values to the object that you defined in `createForm` automatically. If you want to _get_ these values, just use the helper functions provided by the Entity you created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked exactly what you already get.

`if ($form->isValid ()) {` works when your form is submitted and valid.

Now you get your data that you want with: `$recuperacion = $form->getData ();`

Now you can get values of your form inputs from array you already have:

```
$name = $recuperacion['name'];
```

What else you need? :)

If you want know to INSERT values from form to database, use data you just got from form and set it using setters:

```
$entity = new Entity();
$entity->setName($name);
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data by using `$form->getData()`. However, you should do this with a transformator using one of the form event: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html

In this case, you should listen to the `FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT` event:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

$formFactory->createBuilder()
    // ...
    ->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $modelData = $event->getData();

        // ... edit model data

        $event->setData($modelData);
    })
;
```